# oathtool never agrees with Google Authenticator

Tags: macos, google-authenticator

I use Google Authenticator currently for 2FA, things like connecting to VPN etc. I wanted to see if I could get the six digit code on my OSX box but for some reason `oathtool` never returns the same value as Authenticator. And the Authenticator code works, the `oathtool` one doesn't.

Interestingly, I've also tried in an iOS simulator with https://github.com/mattrubin/Authenticator on the same system and the code it produces agrees with `oathtool` and not Authenticator.

I suspected maybe this a time sync issue, but after manually syncing my OSX time, the code is the same. I'm wondering if maybe there are default parameters in the TOTP algorithm that don't match, but I don't know what they'd be.

The `oathtool` command outputs something like the following

```
% oathtool --verbose --base32 --totp "$SECRET"
Hex secret: ...
Base32 secret: ...
Digits: 6
Window size: 0
Step size (seconds): 30
Start time: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (0)
Current time: 2016-10-20 22:27:22 UTC (1477002442)
Counter: 0x2EF3E06 (49233414)
```

(Note, `$SECRET` above is the same value used to generate the QR code that Authenticator used.)

Any reason why these wouldn't agree?

**Update**

I tried to fiddle with the time 30 seconds on either side of my system's time using

```
oathtool --now "$(perl -e'use DateTime; print DateTime->now()->subtract(seconds=>30)->strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z" )')" -b --totp $SECRET -w 20|sort
```

The perl above generates time in the format of

```
2016-10-20 23:36:15 UTC
```

I also output 20 numbers each time, but none of them seemed to match what I have in Authenticator.

Comment: I assume your using a Google Authenticator on a phone?  TOTP basically works by providing the current time ( from Google in the case of a Google Authenticator specifically) and your secret code.  There is other stuff involved, a full explanation of TOTP, is best left to another question.  Does your system time and the time source from Google agree upon the UTC time?  Try increasing the number of codes you generate, and manually modify the current time, by 30 seconds before and after the actual current time and post the reslts.

Comment: right, Authenticator is running from a phone. ok, I'll give that a shot, thanks

Comment: If you have access to a program like VMWare, load up a Windows Trial VM, and use WinAuth.  See if that agrees.  You sure the secret is correct?

Comment: Note that Google Authenticator has a "sync time against Google" option. Try that, just in case. But other than that, the Google app actually doesn't support anything _but_ the defaults: 6 digits, 30s step.

Comment: well thanks Ramhound for your thoughts, and sorry to waste your time... this turns out to be a _pebkac_ issue, heh. The **secret was wrong**, I had been referencing the wrong chart/secret/QR URL. I had forgotten about a reset to my creds that had occurred. I punched in the right secret and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Since searching for "Google Authenticator oathtool" gets you here, and the answer is partly in the comments, for convenience and completeness...

`oathtool` and Google Authenticator are implementations of [RFC 6238 TOTP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238). TOTP produces a 6 digit output using a HMAC. Though the official Android client is no longer open source, it's not because the TOTP implementation has changed or is "secret".

There are 2 inputs for the HMAC, a number and a secret.
In TOTP the number is the count of time intervals from an epoch, the defaults for both `oathtool` and GA being 30 second intervals ("time step" size), and 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. To be clear, `oathtool` and GA will agree as long as the parameters agree: the epoch and time must be sufficiently close, and the time step and secret must match.

Where required (e.g. some hardware TOTP tokens use a 60 second interval) you can use `-s` to set the interval size, and to accommodate offset/drift you can override what oathtool thinks is "now" (or fudge the epoch).

To troubleshoot, the following is useful:

```
oathtool -v --now  "now -30 minutes" -w 120 --totp $SECRET
```

For a 30 second interval size this will generate a full hour of values, from 30 minutes ago to 30 minutes in the future. From this you can deduce a token offset, or a clock offset (`diff -y` to compare outputs side-by-side can be useful). TOTP uses "unix time", so timezones should not be an issue unless a timezone is "hiding" some large offset of an incorrect clock.

`--now` and `--epoch` use the robust GNU date-time parser and support relative time specifications as well as absolute timestamps, `--now "30 min ago"` also works.

As the OP determined, for the default epoch and timestep, if the time is correct, then it must be the secret that is not.

Answer (score 0):

I synced Google Authenticator and oathtool:

```
secret=`echo 1234567812345678 | base32`
oathtool -v --totp -b $secret
qrencode -t ANSI "otpauth://totp/test?secret="${secret}""
```